# Show context menu for some items in NSOutlineView

Tags: c#, cocoa, monomac

I have a SourceList (NSOutlineView) and I want to display a context menu for some of the items. Looking around I have found answers in Cocoa and Obj-C but I am trying to do this in MonoMac and C#.

It seems to me I need to do my own custom class which inherits from NSOutlineView and implement the method MenuForEvent. But when I try to replace my old, standard NSOutlineView with my own custom class, nothing shows up during runtime. In my controller I call View.ReplaceSubviewWith(oldTree, newTree).

Do I need to do something else? Or perhaps there's another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to swap the instance like that, you should be able to do it declaratively.

Make sure you 'Register' your custom outline view, e.g.:

```
[Register("MySourceList")]
private class MySourceList : NSOutlineView
{
    // Need this constructor for items created in .xib
    public MySourceList(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    { }
```

Then, in the Xcode designer, select your outline view and specify the name you registered as the Custom Class for that object:

[image]

That way, when your view is created from the nib, the runtime will create the proper instance of your outline view in the first place.